# Get data from observable grpc service in nestjs,

Tags: node.js, angular, grpc, nestjs, grpc-node

I want to use gRPC service to communicate between my microservices. but when getting a response from Grpc service, before return a method, I want to do some modification and functionality.

sample project:  https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/04-grpc

like this:

```
@Get(':id') 
getById(@Param('id') id: string): Observable<Hero> {
  const res: Observable<Hero> = this.heroService.findOne({ id: +id }); 
  console.log(res); res.name = res.name + 'modify string'; 
  return res;
}
```

but show below message in console.log instead of the original response.

```
Observable { _isScalar: false, _subscribe: [Function] }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do this is to [convert](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise) your `Observable` to a `Promise` using e.g. [`lastValueFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom) and await this promise. You can then modify and return the result:

```
@Get(':id') 
async getById(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<Hero> {

  const res:Hero = await lastValueFrom(this.heroService.findOne({ id: +id }));
  
  res.name = res.name + 'modify string'; 
  return res;
}
```

Note: If you want to stick to `Observable` use bharat1226's solution.

Comment: This is now replaced with [firstValueFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom) and [lastValueFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom). Will be removed in v8. Details: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise

Comment: @Nils: True, feel free to edit my answer :)

Comment: It tells me that the "Suggested edit queue is full". (I also did not know I could edit answers, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Your can use [map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator to transform the emitted value.

In the below code, you are adding string `modify string` to `name`.

```
@Get(':id')
  getById(@Param('id') id: string): Observable<Hero> {
    return this.heroService
      .findOne({ id: +id })
      .pipe(map(item => ({ ...item, name: `${item.name}modify string` })));
  }
```

If any time, you want to log emitted values or perform side effects in an Observable stream, you can use [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator

```
@Get(':id')
  getById(@Param('id') id: string): Observable<Hero> {
    return this.heroService
      .findOne({ id: +id })
      .pipe(tap(item => console.log(item)));
  }
```